# Set file upload limit in azure blob storage

Tags: python, azure, file-upload, azure-blob-storage

Is there any way to limit the number of files that can be uploaded to Azure blob storage say a max of 10. or set a quota for a container?
I found this, this is an old post
[Api to set blob storage container size limit](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/6619366-api-to-set-blob-storage-container-size-limit)
I'm a newbie to azure please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll need to control how many files are still allowed to be uploaded.

Comment: Thanks! @Thiago Custodio